# I want the Orange gear (with class spin) in this SVG to spin using CSS. but it moves around the page 360 degrees. What Am I doing wrong?

Tags: svg

I want the orange gear to spin as a gear spin but not move round around the page. Please help me, What am I doing wrong? Below is my code and I've also given link to codepen.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.spin
{


   -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 5s infinite  linear;
   animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
  from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes spin{
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 143 143" style="enable-background:new 0 0 143 143;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <circle style="fill:#0A76A6;" cx="71.154" cy="72.193" r="71.193"/>
    <path style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);" d="M142.299,74.125l-33.557-33.551c-0.325-0.336-0.793-0.549-1.301-0.549H34.875
        c-1.027,0-1.861,0.844-1.861,1.861V88.73c0,0.449,0.163,0.865,0.448,1.191l0.192,0.193l51.834,51.826
        C117.326,135.434,141.402,107.67,142.299,74.125z"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <polygon style="fill:#E1EFFA;" points="81.089,102.875 61.213,102.875 63.738,90.586 78.563,90.586            "/>
            <polygon style="fill:#CEE2F1;" points="81.089,102.875 78.563,90.586 63.738,90.586 76.023,102.875            "/>
            <rect x="55.892" y="102.875" style="fill:#FFFFFF;" width="30.519" height="1.484"/>
        </g>
        <path style="fill:#364A5E;" d="M34.871,40.027c-1.023,0-1.855,0.838-1.855,1.857v46.844c0,1.025,0.833,1.857,1.855,1.857h72.568
            c1.019,0,1.854-0.832,1.854-1.857V41.885c0-1.02-0.836-1.857-1.854-1.857H34.871z"/>
        <g>
            <rect x="36.872" y="43.881" style="fill:#CEE2F1;" width="68.567" height="42.855"/>
            <rect x="39.364" y="51.869" style="fill:#FFFFFF;" width="63.577" height="32.373"/>
            <rect x="36.872" y="43.881" style="fill:#F78E36;" width="68.567" height="5.496"/>
            <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M101.924,46.67c0,0.447-0.365,0.814-0.812,0.814H61.116c-0.447,0-0.814-0.367-0.814-0.814v-0.08
                c0-0.447,0.368-0.814,0.814-0.814h39.997c0.446,0,0.812,0.367,0.812,0.814V46.67z"/>
            <g>
                <circle style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="44.72" cy="46.63" r="0.854"/>
                <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M50.546,47.484c-0.471,0-0.854-0.385-0.854-0.855s0.383-0.854,0.854-0.854
                    c0.469,0,0.85,0.383,0.85,0.854S51.015,47.484,50.546,47.484z"/>
                <circle style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="56.368" cy="46.63" r="0.854"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <path style="fill:#364A5E;" d="M85.862,61.174v-1.307L84.9,59.541c-0.051-0.293-0.127-0.578-0.227-0.852l0.668-0.766
                    l-0.653-1.133l-0.995,0.197c-0.098-0.111-0.197-0.219-0.3-0.324c-0.105-0.102-0.213-0.201-0.324-0.299l0.198-0.996l-1.134-0.652
                    l-0.765,0.666c-0.273-0.096-0.559-0.174-0.85-0.229l-0.328-0.959h-1.309l-0.328,0.959c-0.293,0.055-0.576,0.133-0.851,0.229
                    l-0.763-0.666l-1.133,0.652l0.197,0.996c-0.111,0.098-0.221,0.197-0.324,0.299c-0.104,0.105-0.204,0.213-0.302,0.324
                    l-0.995-0.195l-0.653,1.131l0.667,0.766c-0.098,0.273-0.174,0.559-0.227,0.852l-0.959,0.326v1.307l0.959,0.328
                    c0.053,0.295,0.129,0.578,0.227,0.852l-0.667,0.764l0.655,1.133l0.993-0.195l-0.002-0.006c0.098,0.113,0.198,0.223,0.304,0.328
                    s0.215,0.207,0.328,0.303l-0.201,0.992l1.133,0.654l0.763-0.668c0.274,0.098,0.558,0.174,0.851,0.229l0.328,0.959h1.309
                    l0.328-0.959c0.291-0.055,0.576-0.131,0.85-0.229l0.765,0.668l1.134-0.654l-0.198-0.994l-0.004,0.002
                    c0.113-0.096,0.223-0.197,0.328-0.303c0.103-0.104,0.202-0.213,0.3-0.324l0.995,0.197l0.653-1.133l-0.668-0.764
                    c0.1-0.273,0.176-0.557,0.227-0.852L85.862,61.174z M79.537,63.135c-1.443,0-2.613-1.172-2.613-2.615
                    c0-1.441,1.17-2.611,2.613-2.611c1.445,0,2.613,1.17,2.613,2.611C82.15,61.963,80.982,63.135,79.537,63.135z"/>
                <g>
            <path class="spin"  style="fill:#F78E36;" d="M76.736,72.818v-2.098l-1.541-0.523c-0.084-0.469-0.207-0.926-0.363-1.367l1.07-1.225
                        l-1.049-1.818l-1.597,0.316c-0.157-0.18-0.313-0.352-0.481-0.52c-0.168-0.166-0.34-0.324-0.518-0.479l0.315-1.598l-1.819-1.049
                        l-1.226,1.07c-0.439-0.156-0.896-0.281-1.365-0.367l-0.524-1.539h-2.1l-0.524,1.539c-0.469,0.086-0.926,0.211-1.365,0.367
                        l-1.224-1.07l-1.82,1.049l0.318,1.598c-0.181,0.154-0.354,0.313-0.521,0.479c-0.165,0.168-0.326,0.34-0.482,0.52l-1.595-0.313
                        l-1.049,1.814l1.069,1.225c-0.155,0.441-0.28,0.898-0.364,1.367l-1.54,0.523v2.098l1.54,0.527
                        c0.083,0.473,0.208,0.924,0.364,1.365l-1.069,1.223l1.051,1.818l1.593-0.313l-0.004-0.012c0.155,0.182,0.318,0.359,0.486,0.527
                        c0.169,0.17,0.344,0.332,0.529,0.484l-0.326,1.592l1.82,1.053l1.224-1.072c0.439,0.158,0.896,0.279,1.365,0.365l0.524,1.539
                        h2.1l0.524-1.539c0.469-0.086,0.925-0.207,1.365-0.365l1.226,1.072l1.819-1.053l-0.315-1.594l-0.008,0.002
                        c0.18-0.152,0.357-0.314,0.525-0.484c0.168-0.166,0.324-0.34,0.481-0.52l1.597,0.316l1.049-1.818l-1.07-1.223
                        c0.156-0.441,0.279-0.893,0.363-1.365L76.736,72.818z M66.59,74.061c-1.266,0-2.291-1.025-2.291-2.291
                        c0-1.262,1.025-2.287,2.291-2.287c1.265,0,2.288,1.025,2.288,2.287C68.878,73.035,67.855,74.061,66.59,74.061z"/>
                    <path style="fill:#364A5E;" d="M66.59,66.846c-2.719,0-4.926,2.207-4.926,4.924c0,2.721,2.207,4.928,4.926,4.928
                        c2.721,0,4.924-2.207,4.924-4.928C71.515,69.053,69.312,66.846,66.59,66.846z M66.59,73.982c-1.222,0-2.211-0.99-2.211-2.213
                        c0-1.219,0.989-2.209,2.211-2.209s2.209,0.99,2.209,2.209C68.799,72.992,67.812,73.982,66.59,73.982z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/nareshramini/pen/LbEKEJ

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps which works on Chrome.

```
.spin
{
   -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 5s infinite  linear;
   animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Robert Longson. It works. All the browsers doesn't support?

Comment: On Firefox it moves weirdly!

Comment: Firefox doesn't implement transform-box yet. Chrome hardcodes transform-box: fill-box but it shouldn't. You'd need to make your viewBox the same as your fill-box (the element bounding box) to get it to work cross platform.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for cross platform solution too! :)

Comment: How do I make it? can you please make those changes in the code and point me the line of code to see the differences you've made to make it work cross platform? Difference between viewBox and fill-box?

Comment: @Naresh compare the answer to the question. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box